# Windows SDK "Samples" dir is missing

Tags: windows, sdk

I want to look at sample code for the Wlan API ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa816369(VS.85).aspx)).

But `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<version number>\Samples\` doesn't exist for me. The only directories there are:

- bin
- Bootstrapper
- FXCop
- Include
- Lib

I got my SDK (v7.0A) by installing the Visual Studio 2010 beta. OS is Windows Vista.